# Failed to create object error in Symfony using sonata admin when data insert into database

Tags: php, symfony

I am facing a problem that I've been trying to fix during the last 5 hours:

I use sonata admin, when i add (insert) data into database using `prePersist()` method it give me error.

---

> Error: Failed to create object: AppBundle\Entity\LanguageTranslationAmount
>   [3/4] NotNullConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO language_translation_amount (from_language_code, to_language_code, amount, currency, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, "5000", "USD", 1, 1, "2017-11-06 09:17:54", "2017-11-06 09:17:54"]:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'from_language_code' cannot be null

---

**LanguageTranslationAmountAdminController file code.**

---

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use AppBundle\Entity\LanguageTranslationAmount;
use Payum\Stripe\Request\Api\CreatePlan;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Form\LanguageTranslationAmountType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Exporter\Source\DoctrineORMQuerySourceIterator;

/**
 * Class LanguageTranslationAmount
 * @package AppBundle\Admin
 */
class LanguageTranslationAmountAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected $datagridValues = array(
        '_sort_order' => 'DESC', // sort direction
        '_sort_by' => 'id' // field name
    );
    protected $perPageOptions = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
    protected $maxPerPage = 10;
    public $id = 0;
     public function getTemplate($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'edit':
                return 'AppBundle:LanguageTranslationAmountAdmin:edit.html.twig';
                break;

            case 'list':
                return 'AppBundle:LanguageTranslationAmountAdmin:list.html.twig';
                break;

            default:
                return parent::getTemplate($name);
                break;
        }
    }

    public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
      $collection->remove('show');
    }

    public function prePersist($object) {
        parent::prePersist($object);
        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $userId = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();

        $object->setFromLanguageCode($object->getfromLanguageCode());
        $object->setToLanguageCode($object->gettoLanguageCode());
        $object->setAmount($object->getAmount());
        $object->setCurrency($object->getCurrency());
        $object->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $object->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $object->setCreatedBy($userId);
        $object->setUpdatedBy($userId);
        $entityManager->persist($object);

        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * @param LanguageTranslationAmountAdmin $object
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function postPersist($object)
    {
        parent::postPersist($object);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $languages = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Language')->findBy(array('status' => 1));
        $language_ary = [];
        foreach($languages as $lang){
            $language_ary[$lang->getName()] = $lang->getId();
        }
        //add
        $formMapper
            /*->add('translations', CollectionType::class,['entry_type' => LanguageTranslationAmountType::class,
                    'entry_options' => array('label' => false)])
            */
            ->add('from_language_code','choice',array('choices'=>$language_ary,'required'=>true))
            ->add('to_language_code','choice',array('choices'=>$language_ary,'required'=>true))
            ->add('currency','choice',array('choices'=>array('USD' => 'USD'),'required'=>true))
            ->add('amount',TextType::class,['required'=>true,'empty_data' => '']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        //filters de sus
        //$datagridMapper->add('translations.name','',array('label' => 'Name'));
        $datagridMapper
            // ->add('slug')
//            ->add('currency', '', array('field_type' => 'choice','field_options' => array('choices'=> array('USD' => 'USD'))))
            ->add('currency', '', array('field_type' => 'choice','field_options' => array('choices'=> array('USD' => 'USD'))))
            ->add('amount');
    }

    public function getExportFields() {
        parent::getExportFields();
        $fields = $this->getModelManager()->getExportFields($this->getClass());
        $fields1 = $this->getModelManager()->getExportFields(Language::class);
        foreach ($fields1 as $f)
        {
            if($f == 'name')
            {
                $fields[] = $f;
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->getExtensions() as $extension) 
        {
            if (method_exists($extension, 'configureExportFields'))
            {
                $fields = $extension->configureExportFields($this, $fields);
            }
        }
        return array('Name' => 'name','Language' => 'someColumnValueAsText');
        /*unset($fields[0]);
        unset($fields[1]);
        dump($fields); die;
        return $fields;*/
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
    */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        //listare tabel
        $listMapper
            ->add('to_language')
            ->add('from_language')
            // ->add('slug')
            ->add('currency','choice',array('choices'=>array('USD'=>'USD')))
            ->add('amount')
            ->add(
                '_action',
                'actions',
                [
                    'actions' => [
                        'edit' => [],
                        'delete' => [],
//                        'pay' => ['template' => ':admin:pay_button.html.twig'],
                    ],
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

---

### **LanguageTraslationAmount entity file code**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LanguageTranslationAmount
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="language_translation_amount")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LanguageTranslationAmountRepository")
 */
class LanguageTranslationAmount
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="from_language_code", type="integer", length=11, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fromLanguageCode;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="to_language_code", type="integer", length=11, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $toLanguageCode;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $amount;


     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $currency;



    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_by", type="integer", length=11, nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_by", type="integer", length=11, nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedBy;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="from_language_code", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var int
     */
    public $fromLanguage;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="to_language_code", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var int
     */
    public $toLanguage;

    /**
     * @return string
    */
    public function __toString()
    {   
        return 'language traslation amount';
    }


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fromLanguageCode.
     *
     * @param int|null $fromLanguageCode
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setFromLanguageCode($fromLanguagecodes = null)
    {
        $this->fromLanguageCode = $fromLanguagecodes;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fromLanguageCode.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getFromLanguageCode()
    {
        return $this->fromLanguageCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set toLanguageCode.
     *
     * @param int|null $toLanguageCode
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setToLanguageCode($toLanguagecodes = null)
    {
        $this->toLanguageCode = $toLanguagecodes;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get toLanguageCode.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getToLanguageCode()
    {
        return $this->toLanguageCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set amount.
     *
     * @param string|null $amount
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setAmount($amount = null)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }


    /**
     * Get currency
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency
     *
     * @param string $currency
     *
     * @return PaymentPlan
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdBy.
     *
     * @param int|null $createdBy
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy = null)
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdBy.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedBy.
     *
     * @param int|null $updatedBy
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setUpdatedBy($updatedBy = null)
    {
        $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedBy.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return $this->updatedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt.
     *
     * @param \DateTime|null $createdAt
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt = null)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt.
     *
     * @param \DateTime|null $updatedAt
     *
     * @return LanguageTranslationAmount
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt = null)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }



    /**
     * Get Language.
     *
     * @return tinyint|null
    */
    public function getfromLanguage()
    {
        return $this->fromLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Set From Language.
     *
     * @param int|null $language_id
     *
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setfromLanguage(Language $language)
    {
        $this->fromLanguage = $language;
        $this->languageId = $language->getId();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Language.
     *
     * @return tinyint|null
    */
    public function gettoLanguage()
    {
        return $this->toLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Set From Language.
     *
     * @param int|null $language_id
     *
     * @return Language
     */
    public function settoLanguage(Language $language)
    {
        $this->toLanguage = $language;
        $this->languageId = $language->getId();

        return $this;
    }

}
```

---

Is there anything missing or wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need to run bin/console doctrine:schema:update to make the translations columns nullable.  If you already have then make sure you don't have any old doctrine mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine